# Why must DNS root servers exists rather than use top-level domain instead?

Tags: dns

As question above, is it possible to store all top-level domain locally? Alough there are many TLDs, but not that much, If we can skip DNS root servers, DNS lookup would definitely speed up. Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## On the false premise of speeding things up

> If we can skip DNS root servers, DNS lookup would definitely speed up.

That premise is false or at least far more complicated than what you seem to see for now.

Every recursive nameserver ships with a list of root nameservers, both names and IP addresses. By a process called root priming, they will contact any of those to get an updated list (IP addresses do change, from time to time). This is cached, as any DNS reply is cached.

Hence, you contact root servers far less often than you think, and hence you do not have really anything to "speed up" here.
This is also true for the level below, the TLDs. By querying the root nameservers any recursive nameserver will get the list of authoritative nameservers for a given TLD, and this will be cached.

Current root zone NS records TTL is 2 days, so your recursive nameserver will never contact root nameservers more than once per 2 days for a given TLD, and you will certainly need resolution of multiple names in the same TLD, so again you have almost nothing to gain here.

## But yes, you can store all TLDs locally

You can store the list of TLDs locally, this is absolutely not a problem.
ICANN lets you download the root zone, the exact same content published by the root nameservers, you just need to go to https://www.internic.net/domain/root.zone for example. Or you can program your own nameserver to do AXFR queries towards some root nameservers that allow those, so that you become a private slave, and have locally the list of all TLDs. See bottom of https://root-servers.org/faq.html

The problem is now mainly how do you make sure this is updated? TLDs come and go, not dozens per day, but changes happen: new TLDs introduced (big wave after 2012, new wave expected for gTLD, small changes in countries too for ccTLDs), or removed (expired or bankrupted gTLDs, countries disappearing, etc.), or change in nameservers set (names or IP addresses).
Do you want now to monitor things so that you have the correct up to date list
(where querying the root nameservers by definition will always give you the up to date content)?

You have also a smaller question aside: how do you ensure authenticity of the content? Do you properly check the certificate attached to the HTTPS resource above? Do you authenticate the AXFR reply? Etc.

In fact for some this is exactly where DNSSEC shines as it can authenticate all records in the root zone, hence it is not important from where you get the content... as long as you can validate it. But to validate it you need a copy of the root zone DNSSEC key, which has already changed over time.

Anyway, that kind of setup is described at length in [RFC 7706 - Decreasing Access Time to Root Servers by Running One on Loopback](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7706) which has the following abstract:

```
Some DNS recursive resolvers have longer-than-desired round-trip
times to the closest DNS root server.  Some DNS recursive resolver
operators want to prevent snooping of requests sent to DNS root
servers by third parties.  Such resolvers can greatly decrease the
round-trip time and prevent observation of requests by running a copy
of the full root zone on a loopback address (such as 127.0.0.1).
This document shows how to start and maintain such a copy of the root
zone that does not pose a threat to other users of the DNS, at the
cost of adding some operational fragility for the operator.
```

You can also read this paper: [On Eliminating Root Nameservers from the DNS](https://www.icir.org/mallman/pubs/All19b/All19b.pdf) by Mark Allman. While the paper is unambiguously in favor of removing the root nameservers, it gives many insightful points on the benefits and drawbacks of doing that.

For more context and about what happens when a recursive nameserver starts, you may wish to have a look also at
[BCP 209 - RFC 8109 - Initializing a DNS Resolver with Priming Queries](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8109) whose abstract is:

```
This document describes the queries that a DNS resolver should emit
to initialize its cache.  The result is that the resolver gets both a
current NS Resource Record Set (RRset) for the root zone and the
necessary address information for reaching the root servers.
```

You can also have a look at this website: https://localroot.isi.edu/
it gives you a way to synchronize the root zone and authenticate it with a TSIG key.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your explaination is so detailed and satisfactory!

Comment: Oops, I see OP has taken my advice to heart and accepted your much more detailed answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Probably for the same reason that you don't have local copies of all six-level DNS names, like `www.paxdiablo.is.good.looking.com`.

Yes, there would be a lot *more* of those (over and above the 13-or-so root level IP addresses) but the main problem is not so much the size as the update strategy.

At the moment, the 13 root servers have specific IP addresses (in reality, there are more than 13 servers but they all get accessed by one of those IP addresses).

Those IP addresses are baked in to the various DNS resolver programs, and they rarely change.

If one *does* have to change, the other 12 will continue to provide services until such point as all DNS resolvers around the planet have their lists updated. In fact, one recent (2107, I think) change to the `L` server was done by running both the old and new IP addresses for a period of six month, before shutting down the old. This would presumably give all DNS resolvers a chance to switch to the new address and therefore never be without the full complement of 13.

So you probably wouldn't want to change all 13 IP addresses in a single change, without some form of parallel serving old and new :-) This provides a great deal of resilience to the lookup system.

However, that resilience would not necessarily be the case for the TLD addresses since they may move from provider to provider at will, and may even change IP addresses *within* a provider. ICANN has much more control over the root domain than it does over the various TLD providers (in terms of their IP addresses), and there are some [1500 TLDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains#ICANN-era_generic_top-level_domains) currently in existence.

In any case, improvements may not be as much as you expect since various DNS resolvers *already* cache multiple levels of the hierarchy, the same way ARP tables on your machines cache the IP-to-MacAddress lookup tables. You should read Patrick Mevzek's excellent answer to this question (and even accept it) since it delves deeper into the technical side of things.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I guess those country TLD is not controled by ICANN.

Comment: "and they never really change." This is not true. See https://root-servers.org/news/b-root-ipv4-address-renumbered.txt for the latest case.

Comment: "So, obviously, you wouldn't want to change all 13 in a single change :-)" Before all root nameservers were called `X.root-servers.net` they were all named in their own domain name, and the change over `X.root-servers.net` happened at once for all of them. But it has of course less consequences than a change of IP addresses.

Comment: "ICANN has much more control over the root domain than it does over the various TLD providers,"  Not really. In TLDs there all gTLDs and ccTLDs, which is purely an administrative split, not a technical one (all TLDs work exactly the same way at the DNS level). Each gTLD is under contract with ICANN. ccTLDs are delegated by ICANN (through IANA/PTI) to governments that handle them the way they want. But even in that case, some ccTLDs signed letters of exchange with ICANN to formerly recognize respective authorities. Relationship between ICANN and ccTLDs is complicated.

Comment: @Patrick, I didn't mean they *never* change (since the following paragraph stated the opposite case), the "never really change" was meant to indicate infrequency. Will clarify answer. The frequency of IP address changes for the 1500-odd TLDs is almost guaranteed to be higher than the frequency for the 15-odd root servers, just because there are a hundred times as many.

Comment: @Patrick, I've also adjusted it to make clear it's the *IP* address changes that would complicate the premise put forth in the question (and I'm not sure the contractual agreements between TLD providers and ICANN go down to that level - they probably specify the process to follow on changes but do not mandate the actual IP addresses to use). If you're hard-coding these IP addresses in the various resolvers, you're correct that changing the DNS names of them is irrelevant.

Comment: "they probably specify the process to follow on changes but do not mandate the actual IP addresses to use)" you can see at https://www.iana.org/domains/root/tld-change-template.txt what IANA requests as data to apply a change in the root zone (the process is now done online and not by email anymore, but the content expected is the same)